# Omitting commas in brief statements

Tags: punctuation, commas, exclamations, imperatives, vocatives

In a brief exhortation followed by the name of a sports team, such as "Let's go, Dodgers!" or "Go, Phillies!" is it ever appropriate to omit the comma?

Comment: The old joke is: "Let's eat grandpa!" This seems like a fairly analogous lesson against dropping the comma, but maybe there are some sport-team exceptions that I forgot about :)

Comment: Read those expressions with and without commas and see for yourself. You'll find rschwieb's comment helpful, too.

Comment: "Let's go [Wild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Wild)!"

Answer (score 1):

In English, the vocative case is designated by separating the vocative noun with a comma.  For example:

> "I don't know, John."
>
> "Out of the way, peasants!"
>
> "Jacob, will you get that for me?"

Because the exhortation *Let's go, Dodgers!* is using the vocative case, a comma is necessary.

Comment: In the asker’s second example, however, “Phillies” is not really a vocative (at least it does not have to be). The formula “Go _noun phrase_” is most commonly used without a comma. In this construction, the noun phrase can be one that cannot semantically have a vocative form (such as phrases with third-person deixis), and it never has vocative unstressing: “Go that guy with the beard bottom left!” or “Go me!”. This is obviously an extension and formulaification (?) of an original imperative + vocative construction, but it’s been extended quite a bit.